# Highchart x-axis shows label shows randomly

Tags: javascript, random, highcharts, weather

i'm dealing with a strange Highcharts error that's kind of random.

---

facts:

- i'm making a weather chart with highcharts
- the chain is: javascript highcharts  -> converts to svg -> converts to png -> use mpdf to generate multiple page pdf with different charts
- the data comes from an external xml, and its parsed with php

---

problem:

- sometimes x-axis label shows date (day number + day label, ex: "10-Feb")
- example of random error in label: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Y5Z.png

---

Anyone knows why this may happen?

Thanks!

Here's the code example:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DiiUyhUY

Comment: There are an awful lot of places where the problem could be happening. You need to narrow it down - check each step of the process to see where the glitch happens. When the chart is generated? When it's converted to SVG? When it's saved as an image? When it's converted to PDF?

Comment: the extracted svg already had the problem (missing days on x-label), so its nots svg->png non either png-pdf.. its javascript / or javascript-svg related

Comment: Try to set [staggerLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#xAxis.labels.staggerLines) as 1.